# create multiple httpserver in a vertx application

Tags: java, vert.x

I am currently working on vertx 3. I access my application by typing **"localhost:8080/home"** and I need to call other routes without changing the URL in the browser address bar. For example I have 2 forms:

```
    <form action="/list" method="POST">
         <input type="text" name="list"/>
         <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

and

```
    <form action="/insert" method="POST">
         <input type="text" name="insert"/>
         <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
```

and I would like to call the URL **"localhost:9090/list"** defined in the action attribute of the first form and the URL **"localhost:9091/insert"** defined in the action attribute of the 2nd form and that **"localhost:8080/home"** remains displayed in the browser address bar. Is it possible to do that with vert.x ?
if you have a sample code, please show me. I thought about Ajax but I do not know if it can do it.

And I wanted to ask if it's a good idea to have multiple verticles listening on different ports (9090,9091,9092, etc). If yes, what is the interest?

Currently I use 2 verticles and when I ask an address for example **"localhost:9090/list"** sometimes it works and sometimes I have **"Resouces not found"** the same for **"localhost:9091/insert"** . If it's a good idea to have multiple verticles, how can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, accessing other ports or sub-domains without leaving the initial page is possible only with AJAX.
   The code could look something like this (jQuery):

   ```
   var form = $( '#myForm' );
   form.submit(function( event ) {
     event.preventDefault();
     $.ajax({
       method: 'POST',
       url:'http://localhost:9091/insert',
       data: form.serialize(),
       ....
     });
   });
   ```
2. Starting http-servers in verticle(-s) under different ports actually represents the idea of **microservices**. If you use the same port, that means you have expose the same service which is scaled across multiple verticles. Of course it doesn't make sense to expose ***the same service*** under different ports and run into the problem of yours.